# Retrieve the query with parameters with pandas.read_sql_query()

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have an sql query that I'm using that passes many dynamic elements as parameters. For my own debugging purposes, I want to save the actual query (with the params entered in) that is submitted to the db.

Is there an easy way to do this? I could write some code that would interpolate the variables into the query, but since pandas is already doing this, I'd love to just be able to save that string to my object.

For example, my query looks somewhat like this (postgres db):

```
select foo, bar
from table 
where table.date >= %(start_date)s
and table.value <= %(threshold)s
```

My code looks like so:

```
sql = '''
select foo, bar
from table 
where table.date >= %(start_date)s
and table.value <= %(threshold)s
'''
params = {'start_date':'2021-01-01', 'threshold':10}

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, db_connection, params=params)
return df
```

What I want to do is add a line like this but where I save the actual query to the object, not the sql with placeholder variables:
`self.query = sql`

Is there a way to retrieve this from the read_sql_query() function in pandas? I've not seen it as I've read the documentation.

Comment: `psycopg2` has [mogrify](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify)

Comment: cool! I'll give it a try